# Django Inline Copy Entry

Tags: python, django, inline-formset

I have been browsing many questions about Django inline, but can't quite find how to do this.

I am using [Django Nested Admin](https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-admin) and am wanting to see how I can copy an existing row in the admin so that when I click on "Add another", it creates the new one as a copy.

Here is an example:

As an example...let's say I am creating a set of recipes. In these recipes, I want to create "variations" with the ingredients. So if I had "Strawberry Smoothie", I want to create a "variation" that has both the regular option, as well as a lactose-free option.

So I have my main model called "Recipe":

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    instructions = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

From here, I then need to add the ingredients, so in my admin.py, I have added:

```
class RecipeAdmin(NestedModelAdmin):
    model = Recipe
    inlines = (VariationsInline,)
```

Using the Nested Inline, I have an inline that allows me to add as many Variations, where each variation can then have as many ingredients inside of it.

The issue I am running into is that sometimes these variations have 10+ ingredients (and their respective quantities) and I have to remake those for each variation I make (which can be potentially 10 times for each dish).

So does anyone know how I can create a "copy" feature so that when I click on "Add Another" it simply copies the first variation that exists?